# Getting specific value from meta_key value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a key_value in my database that looks like this: (long row of variables)

```
a:1:{i:44249684;a:4:{s:11:"shipment_id";i:44249684;s:6:"status";s:37:"onderweg - overhandigd aan vervoerder";s:10:"tracktrace";s:15:"3SMYPA463136003";s:8:"shipment";a:31:{s:2:"id";i:44249684;s:9:"parent_id";N;s:10:"account_id";i:113337;s:7:"shop_id";i:24978;s:13:"shipment_type";i:1;s:9:"recipient";a:11:{s:2:"cc";s:2:"NL";s:4:"city";s:6:"Stadsnaam";s:6:"person";s:13:"John Doe";s:7:"company";s:4:"John";s:5:"email";s:22:"pphendriksma@gmail.com";s:5:"phone";s:10:"0650656148";s:22:"street_additional_info";s:0:"";s:11:"postal_code";s:6:"3992JW";s:6:"street";s:12:"Mispelgaarde";s:6:"number";s:2:"40";s:13:"number_suffix";s:0:"";}s:6:"sender";a:10:{s:2:"cc";s:2:"NL";s:11:"postal_code";s:6:"1234AB";s:4:"city";s:7:"Cityname";s:6:"street";s:10:"Streetname";s:6:"number";s:1:"3";s:13:"number_suffix";s:0:"";s:6:"person";s:28:"T.a.v. Retouren en Reparatie";s:7:"company";s:18:"Car Care Nederland";s:5:"email";s:24:"info@companyemail.com";s:5:"phone";s:10:"1234567890";}s:6:"status";i:3;s:7:"options";a:9:{s:12:"package_type";i:1;s:14:"only_recipient";i:0;s:9:"signature";i:1;s:6:"return";i:0;s:12:"large_format";i:0;s:17:"label_description";s:19:"invoice-number";s:9:"age_check";i:0;s:13:"delivery_type";i:4;s:13:"delivery_date";s:19:"2019-03-12 00:00:00";}s:16:"general_settings";a:4:{s:22:"save_recipient_address";i:1;s:10:"tracktrace";a:10:{s:32:"carrier_email_basic_notification";i:1;s:23:"send_track_trace_emails";i:1;s:26:"email_on_handed_to_courier";i:1;s:3:"bcc";i:0;s:21:"delivery_notification";i:1;s:18:"from_address_email";s:24:"info@companyemail.com";s:20:"from_address_company";s:30:"Company address";s:9:"bcc_email";s:24:"info@companyemail.com";s:7:"send_to";s:22:"customer@email.com";s:7:"send_on";s:19:"2019-03-11 02:21:34";}s:21:"delivery_notification";i:1;s:27:"delivery_notification_email";a:1:{i:0;s:24:"info@companyemail.com";}}s:6:"pickup";a:7:{s:11:"postal_code";s:6:"1234AB";s:6:"street";s:10:"Streetname";s:4:"city";s:6:"Cityname";s:6:"number";s:2:"57";s:13:"location_code";s:6:"205786";s:17:"retail_network_id";s:8:"PNPNL-01";s:13:"location_name";s:5:"shop-name";}s:19:"customs_declaration";N;s:19:"physical_properties";a:10:{s:14:"carrier_height";i:160;s:13:"carrier_width";i:205;s:14:"carrier_weight";i:820;s:14:"carrier_length";i:225;s:14:"carrier_volume";i:7380;s:6:"height";i:0;s:5:"width";i:0;s:6:"length";i:0;s:6:"volume";i:0;s:6:"weight";i:0;}s:7:"created";s:25:"2019-03-10T00:00:00+01:00";s:8:"modified";s:25:"2019-03-11T22:33:18+01:00";s:20:"reference_identifier";s:19:"CCNL-286-2019-03-12";s:10:"created_by";i:21848;s:11:"modified_by";i:21848;s:18:"transaction_status";s:4:"paid";s:7:"barcode";s:15:"3SMYPA463100973";s:5:"price";a:2:{s:6:"amount";i:575;s:8:"currency";s:3:"EUR";}s:6:"region";s:2:"NL";s:17:"external_provider";N;s:20:"external_provider_id";N;s:14:"payment_status";s:4:"paid";s:10:"carrier_id";i:1;s:11:"platform_id";i:1;s:6:"origin";s:11:"woocommerce";s:10:"user_agent";s:60:"Wordpress/5.1 WooCommerce/3.5.5 MyParcelNL-WooCommerce/3.1.3";s:19:"secondary_shipments";a:0:{}s:28:"multi_collo_main_shipment_id";N;}}}
```

This key_value can be found in the meta_key: "_myparcel_shipments".
This meta_key is in the table "wp_postmeta".

I currently try to include the Track and Trace on the Invoice PDF via this snippet:

```
// Adding the T-T number to the billing address
add_filter('wpo_wcpdf_after_billing_address', 'wpo_wcpdf_add_tt_number', 10, 2);
function wpo_wcpdf_add_tt_number ( $template_type, $order ) {
if ( !empty( $order->get_meta('_myparcel_shipments') ) && $template_type == 'invoice' ) {
    printf("<span class='vat_number'>Track en trace: %s</span>", $order->get_meta('_myparcel_shipments') );
}
}
```

This snippet works perfectly fine with another meta_key. But the difference is that the other Meta_key only has 1 single key_value, and not as big as the key_value I pasted at the top of this question.
The only part of that long list of variables I'm interested in, is this part:
s:10:"tracktrace";s:15:"**3SMYPA463136003**";s:8:"

This is the result I am trying to achieve:

```
Track en trace: 3SMYPA463136003
```

Or in HTML:

```
<span class="vat_numer">Track en trace: 3SMYPA463136003</span>
```

The value in bold is the part I want to show on the invoice. It is in the beginning of the value. I am fairly basic in PHP knowledge and somebody else wrote the snippet above for me. Unfortunately he isn't able to help me at the moment.

To show that there is some form of regularity in the code, these are a few other ones:

```
s:10:"tracktrace";s:13:"3SMYPA3002252";s:8:"
s:10:"tracktrace";s:13:"3SMYPA1004047";s:8:"
s:10:"tracktrace";s:15:"3SMYPA300504864";s:8:"
s:10:"tracktrace";s:15:"3SMYPA600206705";s:8:"
s:10:"tracktrace";s:13:"3SMYPA2004858";s:8:"
s:10:"tracktrace";s:15:"3SMYPA700795279";s:8:"
```

Can somebody explain to me how I can filter out the part I need, so my code snippet gives the correct result?

*For privacy reason, I have edited the Track en Trace numbers and hidden customer name, address and other personal data.

Comment: This is PHP’s `serialize` format - so `unserialize` it first, and then pick what you need from the resulting data structure.

Comment: Can you please show how did you store this meta data for an order ? I mean the code snippet where you stored this meta data.

Comment: @04FS, Thanks for that, I will have to Google how to unserialize data first. Hopefully it's fairly easy to learn.

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh, I'm afraid I don't know where to find that bit. I'm using a WooCommerce plugin called MyParcel that does this for me, and I'm not really sure where in the many PHP files I need to search.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: can you do one thing ? please show the output of =>  $order->get_meta('_myparcel_shipments',true); and $order->get_meta('_myparcel_shipments',false);

Comment: I will see what I can do @ShoyebSheikh

Comment: Till thus far I am only getting Syntax errors on that PHP code. I feel there is something missing, or a typo, but I don't have the experience to find it. The code has been entered as: <?php
$order->get_meta('_myparcel_shipments',true); and $order->get_meta('_myparcel_shipments',false);
?>

Comment: I mean first you run it with true, var_dump the values and then run it with false and dump the values.

Comment: First  $order->get_meta('_myparcel_shipments',true); and next  $order->get_meta('_myparcel_shipments',false); not together one by one, I just want to compare the values of these two statements.

Comment: Sorry, my lack of PHP knowledge made me misunderstand. I've put your PHP code in "PHPCode Snippets" (because Wordpress won't allow PHP in a page or post). And then included that snippet in a test-post via the right shortcode.
The result is that nothing that comes after the snipper is loaded. The HTML generated stops at the place where the shortcode is.

Comment: the shortcode is.
I tested the PHP by manually putting into a PHP file in my theme, and then opened the page that uses that PHP file (I put in a custom page template). The result is still that no HTML after the PHP code is generated. If I put the PHP at the top, just after the BODY tag. The page is blank and the HTML stops after <body>.
Tried with both false and true in the code.